# Is the generator inside thermal power plants a synchronous type or asynchronous one?

Tags: power, generator, thermal, synchronous, power-grid

Are thermal power plants connected to the electric power grid based on synchronous generation or asynchronous one? If a mix, which is the main one?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "thermal units" here?

Comment: @jwh20 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_power_station . Therefore coal power plants, nuclear power plants, geothermal power plants, gas power plants, combined cycle power plants, etc...

Comment: What makes a power station synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the rotating machine that produces electricity

Comment: I really doubt the generator type is depending on the type of the turbine... I might be wrong of course, but I don't see any reason for the dependency.

Comment: @EugeneSh. how do you think electricity is produced in a thermal power plant? There is a thermal source which makes a turbine rotating which is connected to the shaft of an electrical machine which produce energy. My question is if this electrical machine is a synchronous one or not

Comment: As I said, the machine which is producing the energy (the generator) does not depend on the type of the input energy which is rotating the turbine -  thermal, hydro, wind whatsoever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wound-field synchronous generators are used for most power generation applications. They have two big advantages over induction generators and permanent-magnet synchronous generators. First, the field can be adjusted to regulate voltage independently from the frequency regulation. Second, they can supply reactive volt-amperes as well as real power.

Induction generators and permanent-magnet synchronous generators are more difficult to control. They generally require all or a substantial portion of the power to be delivered through a power converter. They generally require a large bank of power-factor compensation capacitors to accommodate typical loads. Induction generators are generally less efficient generators.

There may be some construction limitations that prevent induction machines from being manufactured in power ratings as high as those available in synchronous machines.

Comment: Thank you very much charles!! I got it!

Answer (score 2):

Large utility scale generators are almost exclusively synchronous generators.  These may range from smaller MW gas turbines all the way up to 1150 MW nuclear units.

The thermal source is what varies (coal, natural gas, nuclear fission etc.).

I have never seen nor heard of an asynchronous machine driven by thermal source.  The whole idea behind using the asynchronous machine ([dfig](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly-fed_electric_machine)) is that it can generate when the driving force (e.g. wind) can’t push synchronous speed.  The rotor has a low frequency AC current (instead of the DC current we have in a synchronous machine) so that the resultant output current from the machine is synchronous.  The differential between the rotor rotating field and the stator rotating field produces synchronous frequency output.

When I think of an asynchronous generator I’m thinking of a wind generator (doubly fed induction generator).  I did see some documentation on modifying the synchronous machines of pump storage hydro so they could be operated like dfig but can’t remember the manufacturer.  Probably GE.

Comment: Thank you very much relayman! I got it!